# How to make a grid span the remaining height of the page

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am just trying to create a basic website using Material Design Light that responds to the size of the screen and I am having trouble making the grid fill all of the available height. I have tried to look for solutions to this problem online but I cant find any that work.

Here is the source code for one the grids I will use:

```
<main class="mdl-layout__content"> 
    <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col" style="text-align:center; background-color:gray;">size 4</div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col" style="text-align:center; background-color:gray;">size 4</div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col" style="text-align:center; background-color:gray;">size 4</div>        
    </div> 
</main>
```

Here is a link to the full Html page: [Example MDL Page](http://pastebin.com/kH9J8Lrq)

Here is an image of the problem: [Page Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvflS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your page height is the view height, which you can only use w/ modern browsers. [See view height](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Basically what we're doing here is we already know how high our footer and header are going to be (in the fiddle i just set it to 50px each). Then we use the `calc` CSS property to set the `view height (vh)` to 100% - 100px (meaning the footer and header's height put together (50+50 = 100)

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8v9b4fL4/)

```
<div id="main-body">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content clearfix">
        <div class="a">1</div>
        <div class="a">2</div>
        <div class="a">3</div>
        <div class="a">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;  /* add for browser prefixes */
}

#main-body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header, .footer {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
.content .a {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    background-color: red;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
    display:table;
}
```

Note that you'll also need the viewport meta tag in your `<head>` for this to work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

---

**OP added the he would like the ability to center the text within these content divs**

```
<div id="main-body">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content clearfix">
        <div class="a"><p>1</p></div>
        <div class="a"><p>2</p></div>
        <div class="a"><p>3</p></div>
        <div class="a"><p>4</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
#main-body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header, .footer {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
.content .a {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    background-color: red;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.content .a p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
    display:table;
}
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to make the text centered vertically? (without using jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Th way I did it was to over-ride a couple of the mdl styles, notably to make `main` display as `flex` rather than `inline-block`. It would probably make sense to add an Id to restrict the impact of this override across the rest of your site

```
.mdl-layout__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .mdl-grid {
        width: 100%;
        flex-grow: 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to fool around with the CSS height attribute. Like so:

```
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col" style="text-align:center; background-color:gray; height:100%;">size 4</div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col" style="text-align:center; background-color:gray; height:100%;">size 4</div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col" style="text-align:center; background-color:gray; height:100%;">size 4</div>
```

More information here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't do anything for some reason.

Comment: You should provide answers to questions, and practical examples. `height:100%` only works if you set height on parent container.